# Give two data to value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the correct way to give two data to value={}:

```
<MenuItem key={doc.id} value={`${doc.codigo} - ${doc.nome}`}> {`${doc.codigo} - ${doc.nome}`}</MenuItem>
```

The MenuItem need the value, and to work i need to give to him the two data from equipamentos (codigo and nome)

Basically when i press to edit the data, works, but give this warning - ( You have provided an out-of-range value `AD - Administrativo` for the select component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are "").

I am sure its because of value={`${doc.codigo} - ${doc.nome}`}

code:

```
 const [equipamentos, setEquipamentos] = useState("");
 

      useEffect(() => {;
    
         getAllDataEquipamentos();

   }, []);



   useEffect(() => {
        if (id !== undefined && id !== "") {
         editHandler();
      }

     }, [id]);

   const getAllDataEquipamentos = async () => {
         const dataEquipamento =
    await EquipamentoDataService.getAllDataEquipamentos();
   onSnapshot(
     query(collection(db, "codEquipamento"), orderBy("codigo")),
       (snapshot) => {
        setDataEquipamentos(
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
     );
   }
 );
 console.log(dataEquipamento.docs);
};

   const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
setMessage("");
if (equipamentos === "" ) {

  setMessage({ error: true, msg: "Todos os campos necessários" });
  return;
}
const newData = {
  equipamentos,
};
console.log(newData);

try {
  if (id !== undefined && id !== "") {
    await ManutencaoDataService.updateData(id, newData);
    setDataId("");
    setMessage({ error: false, msg: "Atualiazado com sucesso!" });
  } else {
    await ManutencaoDataService.addData(newData);
    setMessage({
      error: false,
      msg: "Nova Manutenção adicionada com sucesso!",
    });
  }
} catch (err) {
  setMessage({ error: true, msg: err.message });
}

setEquipamentos("");

};

const editHandler = async () => {
setMessage("");
try {
  const docSnap = await ManutencaoDataService.getData(id);
  console.log("the record is :", docSnap.data());

  setEquipamentos(docSnap.data().equipamentos);
  
} catch (err) {
  setMessage({ error: true, msg: err.message });
 }
};


return (
    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
    <FormControl sx={{ width: 525 }}>
      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Equipamento</InputLabel>
      <Select
      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
      id="demo-simple-select"
      value={equipamentos}
      label="Equipamento"
      onChange={(e) => setEquipamentos(e.target.value)}
      MenuProps={MenuProps}
    >
      {dataEquipamentos.map((doc) =>(
            <MenuItem key={doc.id} value={`${doc.codigo} - 
      ${doc.nome}`}>{`${doc.codigo} - ${doc.nome}`}</MenuItem>
          ))}
    </Select>
        </FormControl>
        </Form.Group>
        );
```

Comment: What is the current value of `equipamentos` ?

Comment: use like this, `<MenuItem key={doc.id} codigoValue={doc.codigo} nomeValue={doc.nome}></MenuItem>` then get `codigoValue` and `nomeValue` extract with `props.nomeValue`

Comment: Please provide your `MenuItem` component code

Comment: @KevinYobeth  this is from MUI library - https://mui.com/components/selects/